# Closed form of the solution of a nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I should solve the following problem: given a function $u(x)$, the sum of the function and its reciprocal must be equal to the integral of the function raised to $k$. Taking the derivative of the two members, left and right, I get the following differential equation:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(u(x)+\frac{1}{u(x)}\right)=u(x)^k$$
that can be transformed in:
$$u(x)'\left[ 1-\frac{1}{u(x)^2}\right]-u(x)^k=0$$
Its solution can be expressed in closed form for $k=1$ using the $LambertW$ function.
Also for $k=2$ and $k=3$ there are solutions in a closed form. Is it possible to find a closed form solution for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$?
Thanks.

Comment: It can be expressed via solution of an algebraic equation of order $k+1$ (namely, $z^{k+1}-z^{k-1}=a$). Is that suitable? I doubt one can find more explicit representation.

Comment: @O.L. If it's inpossible to find something better, this could be useful

Comment: Well this is straightforward integration. Even for $k=4$  the corresponding algebraic equation is not solvable explicitly for any $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the equation as 
$$
\frac{u'}{u^k}-\frac{u'}{u^{k+2}}=1.
$$
Integrate to get
$$
\frac{1}{(1-k)u^{k-1}}+\frac{1}{(k+1)u^{k+1}}=x-x_0,
$$
where $x_0$ is a free constant. This relation can be rewritten as
$$
u^{k+1}(x_0-x)(1-k^2)+u^2(k+1)+1-k=0.
$$